# SLIM ошибка GET-запроса

Tags: php, slim

имеется Url, по которому в мобильном приложении запрашиваю населенные пункты, похожие на строку запроса

Запрос: `http://localhost/Retrofit/public/cities?query="Москва"`

Код:

```
$app->get('/cities', function (Request $request, Response $response) {
    if(isTheseParametersAvailable(array('query'))){
        $requestData = $request->getParsedBody();
        $query = $requestData['query'];

        $db = new DbOperation();
        $cities = $db->getAllCities($query);
        $response->getBody()->write(json_encode(array("cities" => $cities)));
    }

});
```

Возвращает пустой список.
Если я изменю чуть код и вставлю значение по умолчанию:

```
$app->get('/cities', function (Request $request, Response $response) {
        $requestData = $request->getParsedBody();

        $query = 'Москва';
        $db = new DbOperation();
        $cities = $db->getAllCities($query);
        $response->getBody()->write(json_encode(array("cities" => $cities)));


});
```

То работает все нормально. В чем ошибка приема параметра?

Comment: `isTheseParametersAvailable` возвращает `true`? `$requestData`  содержит что?

Comment: В запросе у Москва не должно быть кавычек

Comment: @ЮрийСПб такой же результат

Comment: @u_mulder да, содержит null

Comment: Ну и если `$requestData` содержит NULL то что вы ждете от `$requestData['query']`?

Comment: @u_mulder, ну а как там не может быть значение, если я его в параметре передаю. http://localhost/Retrofit/public/cities?query="Москва"

Comment: @danilshik, вот так можно параметр достать: `$paramValue = $app->request()->get('query');` и кавычки надо убрать из значения параметра запроса.

Comment: Судя по названию `getParsedBody` работает __не__ с `GET` запросом.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Не видит app, потом не видит request(), потом метод get()

Comment: @danilshik, ну, значит надо как-то так: `$paramValue = $request->get('query')`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб К сожалению нет. Fatal error: Call to undefined method Slim\Http\Request::get() in C:\wamp64\www\Retrofit\public\index.php on line

Comment: getAttribute тоже выдает пустой json

Comment: Ну а [если](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/v3/objects/request.html) `$paramValue = $request->getUri()->getQueryParams()['query']`?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Fatal error: Call to undefined method Slim\Http\Uri::getQueryParams()

Comment: @danilshik, ну, может вы какую-то фервию фреймворка с изменнённым API используете. Посмотрите в документации что сказано о вытаскивании параметра для вашей версии.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб сработало так: $query = $request->getQueryParams('query');

Answer (score 1):

Решение проблемы: `$query = $request->getQueryParam('query');`